# Leaking fuel injectors on Buick 3800 SFI engine

Tags: rough-idle, fuel-injectors

My 1993 Buick LeSabre 3800 seems to have one or more leaky fuel injectors. During idle, especially when fully warmed up, it idles chuggy, like extra rich or flooding. If I shut it off during idle, it seems flooded if I restart. I have to throttle it and clear the excess fuel. But if I rev to 2000 rpm before shut off, it restarts better.
I have been adding Seafoam to each gas fillup, with small effect. Is there a way to clean the injectors safely? Could I determine if it is just one or more injectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways you could find the leaky injector:

1. When the engine appears to be flooded, pull the spark plugs and see which one is wet or fouled. This is the best solution.
2. Loosen the fuel rail but leave the lines attached. Pressurize the rail and visually see which one leaks.

Regarding cleaning them, there are arguably better solvents than Seafoam to add to the gas tank. You can try a "professional" type formula like BG44K, but honestly it is hard to measure the effectiveness of these solvents. The best answer is of course to professionally clean the injectors off vehicle.